# Recommended Frequency Range for Commercial Robot Odometry Systems

Tags: mobile-robot, odometry

I'm looking for insights on the recommended frequency range for odometry in commercial robots. Specifically, I'm interested in what frequency range is generally considered effective for maintaining accurate navigation and responsive control. Any shared experiences or guidelines would be greatly appreciated.